# Derive section number in NSFetchResultsController

Tags: uitableview, date, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using Core Data with an NSFetchedResultsController to show a list of events organized by date sections in a UITableView. A date can have multiple events (rows in sections), as follows:

```
Date 1
  Event A
  Event B
  Event C
Date 2
  Event D
Date 3
  Event E
  Event F
```

There can be any number of events at a certain date.
I want to be able to scroll to the section that contains today's date, or--if there are no events for today--to the nearest date.

I create an NSIndexSet to find the first index of the object that contains a date that is later than today:

```
NSDate *dateToday = [NSDate date];
NSIndexSet *datesAfterToday = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                               ^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                   Event *event = (Event *)obj;
                                   NSDate *dateToCheck = event.date;
                                   NSTimeInterval interval = [dateToday timeIntervalSinceDate:dateToCheck];
                                   if (interval <= 0) {
                                       *stop = YES;          // Only need first occurrence of date
                                       return YES;
                                   }
                                   return NO;
                               }];

NSInteger index = [datesAfterToday firstIndex];
```

This will get me the index of the first event after today. For example if Date 2 is the first date that is later than today, then the above code fragment will get me index 3 (for Event D).
However, I would like to be able to scroll to section 1 (Date 2) and therefor I need the section number; in this case section 1.

So the question is: how can I get this section number given that I have the absolute index number? Or are there other ways to search the NSFetchedResultsController to find the section number?

Any help is appreciated.
Tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` has a method `indexPathForObject:` to get the index path (section and row number) for an object:

```
NSDate *dateToday = [NSDate date];
__block NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
NSArray *events = [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
[events enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Event *event, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDate *dateToCheck = event.date;
    NSTimeInterval interval = [dateToday timeIntervalSinceDate:dateToCheck];
    if (interval <= 0) {
        indexPath = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:event];
        *stop = YES; // Only need first occurrence of date
    }
}];

if (indexPath != nil) {
    // indexPath is the table view index path of the event.
    // You can use indexPath.section, indexPath.row,
    // Or perhaps this:
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath ...]
} else {
    // All events are before the current date ...
}
```

*Note:* Your algorithm finds the first event after `[NSDate date]`, which is the current *date and time*, and not *today*. For example if it is 8pm, the algorithm finds the first event on or after "today 8pm", which might be an event for tomorrow.

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly! Thank you very much. And indeed, the first event after, say, "today 8am" is exactly what I need.